# battery drain- Panasonic T 41

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My battery drains every 2 min when I use else remains constant. Takes 3-5 minutes to step a point of charge. Battery usage states WiFi taking 32 and idle as 32 percentage whereas my WiFi Is off 
Android KitKat 4.2.2

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Your battery drains when you use what? Wifi takes 32% when on and idle takes 32% when WiFi is off? What about the idle usage when WiFi is on?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that may be happening because of bugs. I would say why don't you try testing your battery. You need to remove your battery and put it over the flat surface and then try spinning it, if the battery spins freely then the battery is swollen and needs replacement. I think you should first try checking your battery out.